# Returning distinct results for each value combination

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return a random ID for each year and code combination that is used. The database is quite large, so i'm trying to get a random sample for testing and need to make sure each year and code is represented.

A fair example would be to assume there's over a hundred ID's for every combination, but the year and code are limited. I'm hoping to get a result that would look like the following

| YEAR | CODE | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | CODE_A | -RANDOM ID FOR THIS YEAR/CODE COMBINATION |
| 2015 | CODE_B | -RANDOM ID FOR THIS YEAR/CODE COMBINATION |
| 2015 | CODE_C | -RANDOM ID FOR THIS YEAR/CODE COMBINATION |
| 2015 | CODE_D | -RANDOM ID FOR THIS YEAR/CODE COMBINATION |
| 2015 | CODE_E | -RANDOM ID FOR THIS YEAR/CODE COMBINATION |
| 2016 | CODE_A | -RANDOM ID FOR THIS YEAR/CODE COMBINATION |
| 2016 | CODE_B | -RANDOM ID FOR THIS YEAR/CODE COMBINATION |
| 2016 | CODE_C | -RANDOM ID FOR THIS YEAR/CODE COMBINATION |
| 2016 | CODE_D | -RANDOM ID FOR THIS YEAR/CODE COMBINATION |
| 2016 | CODE_E | -RANDOM ID FOR THIS YEAR/CODE COMBINATION |

..etc. For all year/code combinations. I'm currently using:

```
select year, code, id from 
  (
  select * 
  from table1
  order by dbms_random.value
  )
where rownum <= 25
order by year;
```

This will get me 25 random parcels, but it's not guaranteed to represent every year/code combination. I've searched where I could and I apologize if I missed something obvious. I may not have searched correctly. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year, code order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want more than one row per combination, just use `seqnum <= <n>`.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for.